# dynamic routing with camel don't forward messages

Tags: java, apache-camel, dynamic-routing

I am working on a dynamic routing manager in Camel based on webservice and jms queue. I have this following architecture:

```
endpoint:cxf -> jms:queue -> dynamic routing to a jms:queue -> processing
```

Here is a my route definition:

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    routeDefinition = from(fromEndpoint).routeId(name)
            .dynamicRouter(method(DynamicRoutingManager.class, "getRoute")).process(exchange -> {
                final List<?> soaList = exchange.getIn().getBody(List.class);
                final String type = (String) soaList.get(0);
                final String documentNumber = (String) soaList.get(1);
                final String productionStepNumber = (String) soaList.get(2);
                final String message = (String) soaList.get(3);

                final String messageToSend = "Route ID=" + name + ", from=" + fromEndpoint + ", type=" + type
                        + ", document number=" + documentNumber + ", production step number" + productionStepNumber
                        + ", message=" + message;
                LOG.debug("==> message={}", messageToSend);
                exchange.getOut().setBody(messageToSend);
            }); // .to(DLQ);
}
```

and here my dynamic routing manager (i keep it simple):

```
public String getRoute(String body, @Header(Exchange.SLIP_ENDPOINT) String previous) {
    LOG.debug("========> BODY={}", body);
    return "jms:topic:urgent_doc1_prod1";
}
```

the route `jms:topic:urgent_doc1_prod1` is defined at the runtime and running (view in the logs)

the fact is when I send a request like that (see below) I get a timeout error...

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:hel="http://cxf.apache.org/wsse/handler/helloworld">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <hel:message>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <type>urgent</type>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <document_number>1</document_number>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <production_step_number>1</production_step_number>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <message>un message</message>
      </hel:message>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Cause I think my message is not forwared to the second jms:queue, so any processing can be done...

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use `recipientList` or `toD` if you want to route the message to a single dynamic destination - see this FAQ: http://camel.apache.org/how-to-use-a-dynamic-uri-in-to.html

The dynamic router is like a `while loop` that keeps routing until you tell it to stop by empty / null destination. See the docs in the top: http://camel.apache.org/dynamic-router.html. And your example does not do that as its a hardcoded destination value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work.The message is enqueued in `jms:topic:urgent_doc1_prod1` but never dequeued and ends in the DLQ..

Comment: I dont grok your question. Are you doing some kind of request/reply over JMS and want Camel to wait for a reply message before continuing.

Comment: I create dynamically routes at runtime with an user interface and the dynamic part is used to forward messages (according to the options defined in the request) over these dynamic routes. At the end, and for the moment, I just want to send a processed message (with the content of the initial the request)

Comment: The problem is that there is no consumer for `jms:topic:urgent_doc1_prod1`. But I defined a processor..

Comment: Then send the message using InOnly (eg one way / fire and forget mode) instead of potential InOut (request / reply) see http://camel.apache.org/event-message.html

Comment: thanks for your remarks, it helped to improve my code

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it was a misconception from me. I didn't declare the "from" route independantly after the dynamic routing, so there was no consumer, so timeout.

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from(fromEndpoint).routeId(name + "a").recipientList(method(DynamicRoutingManager.class, "getRoute"));

    from(toEndpoint).routeId(name + "b").process(exchange -> {

        final List<?> soaList = exchange.getIn().getBody(List.class);
        final String type = (String) soaList.get(0);
        final Integer documentNumber = (Integer) soaList.get(1);
        final Integer productionStepNumber = (Integer) soaList.get(2);
        final String message = (String) soaList.get(3);

        final String messageToSend = "Route ID=" + name + ", from=" + fromEndpoint + ", type=" + type
                + ", document number=" + documentNumber + ", production step number" + productionStepNumber
                + ", message=" + message;

        LOG.debug("==> message={}", messageToSend);
        exchange.getOut().setBody(messageToSend);
    });
}
```

make it works.